# Redirecting user to a specific page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and Auth by default with [this roles package](https://github.com/httpoz/roles). How can i do the normal user redirection after ***the user login*** if i have similar roles and also pages for them. For example i have **AdminRole** and after the **Login** i want to redirect user to `/admin/dashboard`.

I have tried something like this in the `LoginController` but it doesn't make sense:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    if (Auth::user()->isRole('admin'))
        return redirect()->route('admin');

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Or maybe there is a better way to use `middleware` for redirecting?

Here is my routes (`web.php`):

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::resource('company', 'CompanyController');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {


    Route::get('login', function () {
        return view('admin.pages.admin-login');
    });


    Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:admin'], function () {
        Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('admin.admin-main');
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: show your route part

Comment: where is your post login, you may set the postlogin route to redirectTo()

Comment: @KrisRoofe `Auth::routes();` This is all routes for Login, Register etc.

Comment: return redirect("admin");

Answer (score 0):

use it like this way:

```
return Redirect::to('admin');
```

And note that:

route:`Route::get('company', 'CompanyController@show');`

controller:
this works fine:

```
function show(){
  return Redirect::to('home');
}
```

but this not

```
function show(){
  $this->redirectto();
}

function redirectto()
{
   return Redirect::to('home');
}
```

Comment: I used it in the `redirectTo` method, doesn't working.

Comment: is your redirectTo the route function

Comment: Ok I guess not, you cannot use like that way. you must put Redirect::to In the route function.

Comment: No, it's a method in the LoginController.

Comment: `Auth::routes();` this is my routes for login, register etc. It's a default Auth coming from Laravel 5.3

Comment: Sorry, but it's not what i need. I also edit my question. I forgot to note that i want redirect after the user login.

Answer (score 0):

**route.php**

```
Route::get('home', ['as' => 'admin_home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
Route::get('login'['as'=>'admin_login','uses'=>'LoginController@admin_login']);
```

**LoginController.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

public function index(){
    $User=new User();

    if(isset(AUTH::user()->id)){
        $User->id=AUTH::user()->id;
        $auth_user_role=$User->auth_user_role();
        $rl_title=$auth_user_role[0]->rl_title;

        if(isset(Auth::user()->id) && isset($rl_title) && $rl_title == 'Admin'){
            return view('home.admin',$this->param);
        }
        else if(isset(Auth::user()->id) && isset($rl_title) && $rl_title == 'Moderator'){
            return view('home.moderator',$this->param);
        }
        else{
            return Redirect::route('admin_login');
        }
    }else{
        return Redirect::route('admin_login');
    }
}
```

**Views**

```
-> views
    -> home
        -> admin.blade.php
        -> member.blade.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something like this in Auth/LoginController:

```
protected function authenticated()
{
    if(Auth::user()->isRole('admin')) {
        return redirect()->intended('/admin');
    }

    return redirect()->intended('/home');
}
```